# Program keeps going straight to else statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

```
number1 = float
number2 = float


number1 = raw_input("Please input the first number: ")
number2 = raw_input("Please input the second number: ")


if number1 > number2:
    print number1 + ' is bigger than ' + number2

elif number2 < number1:
    print number2 + ' is bigger than ' + number1

else:
    print 'You did not follow the instructions properly. Goodbye!'


print "\n"
raw_input("Please press enter to exit.")
```

Comment: What inputs did you test it with?

Answer (score 5):

These lines:

```
number1 = float
number2 = float
```

do not make the inputs into floats.  Instead, all they do is assign the variables to the built-in `float`.

This is what you should be doing:

```
number1 = float(raw_input("Please input the first number: "))
number2 = float(raw_input("Please input the second number: "))
```

---

Also, inside your if-statements, you cannot add strings and floats together (trying to do so will raise a `TypeError`).  There are two ways to solve this problem.  The first is with [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print '{} is bigger than {}'.format(number1, number2)
```

The second is to separate the values with commas:

```
print number1, 'is bigger than', number2
```

---

Finally, your logic is a little off.  The second if-statement should be like this:

```
elif number1 < number2:
```

Otherwise, it does the same thing as the first if-statement.

---

Below is a fixed version of your script:

```
number1 = float(raw_input("Please input the first number: "))
number2 = float(raw_input("Please input the second number: "))

if number1 > number2:
    print '{} is bigger than {}'.format(number1, number2)

elif number1 < number2:
    print '{} is bigger than {}'.format(number2, number1)

else:
    print 'You did not follow the instructions properly. Goodbye!'


print "\n"
raw_input("Please press enter to exit.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings, which means they are compared *lexicographically*.

Cast the return value of `raw_input` to float:

```
number1 = float(raw_input("Please input the first number: "))
number2 = float(raw_input("Please input the second number: "))
```

The lines:

```
number1 = float
number2 = float
```

merely store references to the `float()` constructor. Python doesn't have type declarations, and those lines do *not* mean that the two names should only hold floating point values.

You do then need to turn the floating point numbers back to strings when printing; you could use the fact that `print` accepts multiple values to have this done for you:

```
if number1 > number2:
    print number1, 'is bigger than', number2

elif number2 < number1:
    print number2, 'is bigger than', number1
```

Alternatively, you could store the `raw_input()` results as strings and only turn the values to `float()` when comparing:

```
number1 = raw_input("Please input the first number: ")
number2 = raw_input("Please input the second number: ")


if float(number1) > float(number2):
    print number1 + ' is bigger than ' + number2

elif float(number2) < float(number1):
    print number2 + ' is bigger than ' + number1
```

Comment: You will need to explicitly make strings of the values to add to other strings: `str(number2) + ' is bigger than ' ...`